# SQL query only returns 3 rows

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables and I want it to join so I can display all the records in it in an HTML table.

The tables are as follows:

1. laporan
2. doktor
3. pesakit

I used the query `SELECT * FROM laporan NATURAL JOIN doktor NATURAL JOIN pesakit;` to join all the tables.

I've entered 5 records in `laporan` table because it only refers `doktor` and `pesakit` as foreign keys. I've also used the phpmyadmin query tool to display the records with this query.

The problem is, when I use that query, among those 5 records, only 3 can be displayed. What's the problem? There was nothing wrong with the `mysql_fetch_array()` in the php code.

**EDIT:**

This is how the table code looks like:

```
<?php
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM laporan NATURAL JOIN doktor NATURAL JOIN pesakit;");

        $i = 1;

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $i++ . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['doktor_nama'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['pesakit_nama'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['laporan_tarikh'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }


        echo "</tbody>
        </table>";

?>
```

Database structure are as follows:

**doktor:**

- id (PK)
- doktor_nama

**pesakit:**

- id (PK)
- pesakit_nama

**laporan:**

- id (PK)
- laporan_tarikh
- laporan_doktor_id (FK to doktor's id)
- laporan_pesakit_id (FK to pesakit's id)

Comment: without knowing the structure of your tables, we cannot help you. you've gone with "lazy" join syntax, and are simply assuming that mysql can read your mind and figure out which fields should be used for the joins. Obviously it's not working.

Comment: no idea what is wrong it could be everywhere. maybe share some more inside info on how you display the stuff?

Comment: @MarcB I have no idea on what query should be used in my case to make it work.

Comment: and we have no idea what it should be either. You've basically said "here's 3 impenetrable boxes, labeled X,Y,Z. tell me what's inside them"

Comment: @MarcB I see the problem now. My SQL query knowledge is still below average par. Sorry about that, mate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to adding columns to a query, `INNER JOINS` eliminate rows.  If you are expecting your query to return five rows and are only getting three, I suspect that two rows in your **laporan** table have keys that are either NULL or not in the two reference tables.

So, try using `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead, something like this:

```
SELECT lap.*
     , d.doktor_nama
     , p.pesakit_nama
FROM laporan lap
LEFT OUTER JOIN doktor d
   on lap.aporan_doktor_id =d.ID  
LEFT OUTER JOIN pesakit p
   on lap.laporan_pesakit_id =p.ID
```

Comment: Good suggestion. I had not considered that.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This has fixed the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use INNER JOIN instead of NATURAL JOIN like this:

```
SELECT * FROM laporan
    INNER JOIN doktor ON laporan.laporan_doktor_id = doktor.id
    INNER JOIN pesakit ON laporan.laporan_pesakit_id = pesakit.id
```

Comment: Thanks. This should give me more knowledge on how different Joins works :)